# How to search a string in the whole history in perforce

Tags: version-control, perforce

Problem is: I was told that there was once a code containing string "SOMESTRING" existed before and I want to get that snippet. The way I can think of now is to open P4WEB and open changelisht one by one and press Ctrl-F to let the browser search for me. But there are hundreds of changelist in history, I don't want to do this hundreds of times in order to search one string. Is there any way to do it faster like search in the whole history of the codes whether some change contains that string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use p4 grep it can search the whole history.

Comment: Just to add more info, in this case you could use something like:

> p4 grep -a -i -e "SOMESTRING" ...

-a (search all revisions)
-i (case insensitive)
-e (the search string)